# Pass many objects to the controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Help pls. 
I must transfer several users to the party, but I don’t know how to do this, I haven’t seen anything like this anywhere else.
How to make a controller so that you can pass a lot of objects into it to create an entity with ManyToMany connection?

My controller:

```
@PostMapping("/project/{projectId}/party/create")
public String processCreateProjectParty(
        @PathVariable("projectId") Project project,
        @Valid Party party,
        Set<User> users,
        BindingResult bindingResult,
        Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("project", project);
    model.addAttribute("party", party);
    model.addAttribute("users", users);
    Long projectId = projectService.createProjectParty(project, party, users);
    return "redirect:/projects/project/" + projectId;
}
```

My Entity Creation Method

```
public Long createProjectParty(Project project, Party party, Set<User> users) {
    project.addParty(party);
    party.addUsers(party, users);
    projectRepo.save(project);
    return project.getProjectId();
}
```

Helper methods to add bi-directional associations:

```
public void addParty(Party party) {
    party.setPartyProject(this);
    this.projectParties.add(party);
}

public void addUsers(Party party, Set<User> users) {
    party.setPartyUsers(users);
    this.partyUsers.forEach(user -> user.getUserParties().add(party));;
}
```

ManyToMany association mapping:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.REMOVE}
)
@JoinTable(name = "party_users",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "fk_party_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "fk_user_id")})
private Set<User> partyUsers = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: You've done a pretty large code dump here. What exactly are you having issues with? Is it the request? Persistence? What does your payload look like?

Comment: I need to pass many Set <User> users through the controller. 
I don’t know how to pass the Set <User> users collection through the controller(((( This cannot be done through the request parameters. All my attempts to do this somehow gave errors.